# Image from localhost does not appear inside of Telerik RadImageEditor

Tags: asp.net, telerik

When I load the RadImageEditor using an image from localhost, the image does not appear inside of the control. I tested loading an image from a true domain, and the image loads.

Any ideas?

.aspx

```
 <telerik:RadImageEditor ID="rieImageCrop" runat="server" Width="720px" Height="720px">
    <Tools><telerik:ImageEditorToolGroup>
    <telerik:ImageEditorToolStrip CommandName="Undo">
    </telerik:ImageEditorToolStrip>
    <telerik:ImageEditorToolStrip CommandName="Redo">
    </telerik:ImageEditorToolStrip>
    <telerik:ImageEditorToolSeparator></telerik:ImageEditorToolSeparator>
    <telerik:ImageEditorTool CommandName="Crop"></telerik:ImageEditorTool>
    </telerik:ImageEditorToolGroup>
    </Tools>
    </telerik:RadImageEditor>





code behind
    string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"];
    newImage = "http://" + host + profileImageFolder + newImage;
    rieImageCrop.ImageUrl = newImage;




Rendered html.
    <img id="ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_Content2_ucEditMemberPhoto_rieImageCrop_EditableImage"     src="http://localhost:51081/Member/ProfilePhotos/thumbx700_e261f723-fd5b-4518-b103-17b029d615be.jpg" alt="" />
```

Comment: Can you share some of the code you are using to load this image?

Comment: Yes, one idea is that your url to the image is wrong because you are probably hard-coding the path some-how. Perhaps using an absolute path when you should be using a relative path... or maybe a permission issue on IIS. It's impossible to tell without code/markup...

Comment: Okay, I added the code examples... let me know if you need more..

Comment: I also tried this relative URL, to no avail..
<img id="ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_Content2_ucEditMemberPhoto_rieImageCrop_EditableImage" src="/Member/ProfilePhotos/thumbx700_c9da19ef-6301-4bf4-866b-f3f53f078003.jpg" alt="" />

Comment: One other thing, the image seems to be hidden somehow..

If I choose the crop tool on the empty canvas, it can be moved to the outer edges of what would be the image, but there is no image inside the tool.

Comment: Update, this is a random weirdness.
Everything works fine in Firefox.
Breaks in chrome if the image is not an absolute path with a non-localhost url.
http://localhost/image.jpg works in chrome once after a system reboot, does not work after the initial use.
http://www.yahoo.com/image.jpg works everytime in chrome.

Comment: I figured out the problem.. I had a chrome extension loaded that was breaking it...

Rulers, Guides, Eye Dropper and Color Picker 1.1
Thanks